# faced a merge conflict in this following code

Tags: c#, git, testcase

Why do conflicts happen? I need more explanation( clarification) and don't know have I right to ask like this in stack overflow, Its more focuses on Git and I knew some basic information.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string defaultPhrase = "Did you know that ";
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to animal facts");
<<<<<<< HEAD
    Console.WriteLine("Fish are the best");
    Console.WriteLine(defaultPhrase + "fish can breathe underwater?");
=======
    Console.Write("What animal would you like to know about? ");
    string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    if( userChoice.ToLower() == "hedgehog" )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(defaultPhrase + "hedgehogs fear balloons?");
}
>>>>>>> user_input_feature
}
```

Comment: check how to ask a homework question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1. Why do conflicts happen?**
You need to understand the concept of versions and repository. In simple words, it is common place from where all developers check out (fetches) the code base to local machine and work on it.

Lets have an example on a time line.

- 09 AM : Person A and B fetches file.txt
- 10 AM : Person A adds his text "Hello World" at Line number 22 and
  check in the changes in Repository.
- 11 AM : Person B adds her text "Hi World" at Line number 22.

Whenever Person B tries to check in the code, she will get conflicting error as Person A and B were working on same version, but after Person A checked in, the version on which person B is working became old version.

**2.Explain how you solve a general conflict.** Always work on the latest copy of code. Make a habit of updating the code base in everyday. To fix the issue, you have to fix it manually  in your local code base (after taking the update) and commit the code.

**3.Rewrite the code below so that the conflict is resolved, in a manner that takes the purpose of the code into account.** Do it yourself because you are the best person who knows the requirement.

Comment: Welcome. Pls mark it as an answer.